# How does XStream select its converters?

Tags: java, converters, xstream

The only documentation on XStream converters that I can find is on these two pages:

- [Tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html)
- [List of all shipped converters](http://x-stream.github.io/converters.html)

When XStream is parsing XML input, it uses a [`ConverterLookup`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterLookup.html) (and by default, a `DefaultConverterLookup`) to lookup which converter to use by class. I'd like to configure my `XStream` mapper to use my own custom `ConverterLookup`, but only see a `getConverterLookup()` method, not a respective setter.

I have an instance where XStream is encountering a `Date` value in the XML, and returning using the respective `DateConverter`. I want it to use a different converter, which (I believe) means I need to set/register my own `Converter` impl. Just can't figure out how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your question is in fact two unrelated questions, I'll try my best to answer them both.

**Converters**

To your second question regarding date conversion. Which in my mind seems to be the reason why you are here.

The basic way of adding your own converter is rather simple, the method `registerConverter` should give your a clue. If you are wondering how to implement a `Converter` I suggest you take a look at one of the many converters already provided by XStream. On an extra note I feel like I must mention the priority of converters.

> The converters can be registered with an explicit priority. By
>   default they are registered with XStream.PRIORITY_NORMAL. Converters
>   of same priority will be used in the reverse sequence they have been
>   registered. The default converter, i.e. the converter which will be
>   used if no other registered converter is suitable, can be registered
>   with priority XStream.PRIORITY_VERY_LOW. XStream uses by default the
>   ReflectionConverter as the fallback converter.

In other terms, given two converters accepting the same classes, the one who was added last will be used.

**ConverterLookup**

To answer how you can use your `ConverterLookup` there are two ways which may yield the same results, personally I would go for alternative 2.

**1)** Overriding `getConverterLookup`

```
    XStream xs = new XStream(){
        @Override
        public ConverterLookup getConverterLookup() {
            return new ConverterLookup() {

                public Converter lookupConverterForType(Class type) {
                    //Do your magic here
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

**2)** Using a `Mapper`

In this case I would keep the `DefaultMapper` and instead implement `MapperWrapper`'s for my new mappings. (Have a look at `buildMapper` inside of `XStream.java` to see some of the defaults) Initialize like this:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = new ClassLoaderReference(new CompositeClassLoader());
    Mapper mapper = new DefaultMapper(classLoader);
    mapper = new MyOwnMapperWrapper(mapper);
    XStream xs = new XStream(null, mapper, new XppDriver());
```